# .htaccess caching has no effect

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I have an issue with changing cache policy in my server. I have changed .htaccess from:

```
Options -Indexes
```

to:

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 648000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 648000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 648000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers
```

However, this seem to have no effect on caching policy (checked with google page insights). Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe mod_expires is not loaded?

Comment: @OlafDietsche, how can I load//add it?

Comment: You may try `a2enmod expires`.